# iOS - Navigation bar has no back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation

I am currently using a walkthrough view controller to show a "getting started" carousel when you first open my app. Once you select get started, there are two buttons at the bottom that direct you to login as one of two types of users: [image: two types of users:]

However, As you can see here[image: As you can see here,] there is no back button to take you back to the page where you decide what type of user you are. Here is the code I am using to segue:

```
override open func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let NavViewController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
    let NextViewController = NavViewController.topViewController as! LoginViewController
    if(segue.identifier == "client") {

        NextViewController.request = 0;
    } else {

        NextViewController.request = 1
    }

}
```

In addition, I have added titles to all of the other view controllers in their viewDidLoad() methods. If anyone has an idea of why the back button isn't showing, I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: I think you have totally misunderstood how and when to use navigation controllers. There is no back button because there is nothing in the navigation controller stack to back to. You want to embed walkthrough view controller in a navigation controller if you want to be able to go back to there.

Comment: Ok so you're saying the nav controller must be before the initial segue?

Comment: Is walkthrough view controller a tab bar controller? If it is then it will automatically switch between view controllers associated with different logins as they will be attached to the tabs. So in that case there is actually no need for a stack view controller, but it depends on your overall design and where things can lead to. If and where you need one.

Comment: Walkthrough VC is a regular VC with a toolbar at the bottom. But I do understand your answer, I put the Nav-controller further back and now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Question has been answered by Grundewald. Solution: The navbar needs to begin before the initial segue. Thank you for your help!